# How to check the Visual C++ compiler version when using a specific platform toolset?

Tags: visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2013

I have multiple versions of Microsoft Visual C++ installed (2005, 2008, 2012, 2013).
I am moving my project from VC++ 2008 to 2013.

I set "Platform toolset" to "Visual Studio 2013 (v120)".
I set "Additional library directories" to "C:\local\boost_1_55_0\lib32-msvc-12.0" (where a new version of Boost is installed).

So far I have no way to check that the code has been compiled with version 12 (2013) of the compiler. I set the "Suppress Startup Banner" to "No". The only details I get are:

```
    ..\src.cpp(371): warning C4996: 'gmtime': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using gmtime_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
    1>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\time.inl(101) : see declaration of 'gmtime'
...
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.1.6723.1
...
1>boostlibs.lib(archive_exception.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc90.pdb' was not found with '..\..\lib\debug\boostlibs.lib' or at 'C:\Users\me\prj\Debug\vc90.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
```

These lines seem to indicate that version 9 of the compiler is used.

Is this the case?

How can I set a different compiler? How can I check it has really being used?

How can I force the compiler and linker to use a specific version of Boost? I already specified its path in "Additional Include Directories" and in "Additional Library Directories".

Answer (score 2):

> How can I check it has really being used?

You can check the [compiler version macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) in your source:

(possibly with `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(...)`)

> `_MSC_FULL_VER` -- Evaluates to the major, minor, and build number
>   components of the compiler's version number. The major number is the
>   first component of the period-delimited version number, the minor
>   number is the second component, and the build number is the third
>   component. For example, if the version number of the Visual C++
>   compiler is 15.00.20706.01, the _MSC_FULL_VER macro evaluates to
>   150020706. Type cl /? at the command line to view the compiler's version number.
>
> `_MSC_VER` -- Evaluates to the major and minor number components of
>   the compiler's version number. The major number is the first component
>   of the period-delimited version number and the minor number is the
>   second component.
>
> For example, if the version number of the Visual C++ compiler is
>   17.00.51106.1, the _MSC_VER macro evaluates to 1700.

---

> These lines seem to indicate that version 9 of the compiler is used.

... they *may* -- on the other hand, it would be possible (speculation on my part - I don't have a multi-VS machine to check) that the project conversion got messed up, and your VS2013 project now contains explicit "references" to all the VC9 stuff (`vc90.pdb` explicitly set, include path from VS2008 instead of the correct VS2013 one).

Make sure to check the project settings

---

> How can I force the compiler and linker to use a specific version of Boost?

Roughly speaking, the version of Boost you use is determined by the order of your include path. The first Boost version found on the include path should be used.

Since the Boost headers contain linker pragmas, you should not need to set any linker inputs explicitly for the boost `lib` files. Of course the correct lib files need to be on the linker path.

Answer (score 0):

After failing to set the compiler to the new 12.0 version through the Visual C++ GUI, I manually modified the `*.vcxproj` file, substituting all the "9.0" tokens with "12.0".

It now uses the right compiler.